# Does Ethereum support bilinear pairing calculation?

Tags: solidity, pairings

Ethereum pre-compiled x08 address can do pairing checks, but if I just want the smart contract to calculate a pairing, such as e(a,b), instead of checking whether the pairing e(a,b) is equal to e(c,d), what should I do？

Comment: There's a draft proporsal https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1962.